# Linux Kernel acting weirdly

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

This probably is a bug, but I am not sure, that's why I'm posting this here.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 using Linux Kernel `3.13.0-55-generic` on Dual Boot with Win 8.1 on a Lenovo Z510. Lately the booting has been troublesome. These are the things that are happening **randomly** when I select the above kernel:

- It boots up normally
- It shows up a kernel panic saying that it tried to read outside of some hd(0, 0) (Pardon me, I don't remember the exact error message. Also its not completely reproducible as it occurs randomly)
- Grub Menu might not even load and the notebook just **beeps** continuously. This occurs mostly when I restart after a Kernel-Panic-hang.
- It restarts and I end up back at the grub menu.

I overcome this by selecting the `3.13.0-54-generic` kernel in `Advanced options for Ubuntu`. So anyone has any idea why this might be happening?

### Update:

As per Pilot6's comment I have installed `linux-generic-lts-vivid`. The first boot-up was OK but the pointer was missing (It was still there, but not visible). After that, the problem returned and I had to shift back to the `*-54-generic` kernel.

PS: During the installation of the 3.19 kernel, I got an error message at the end about a missing dkms.conf file or something? I don't know if it is related, but wanted to share in case it's useful.

---

Output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380a
Kernel driver in use: i915
07:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380a
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Output of `dkms status`:

```
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
```

Comment: That's probably a bug in kernel. You can report it to launchpad. But I suggest installing 3.19 kernel, that is for Ubuntu 14.04.3. Run `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid` in terminal.

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2` and `dkms status` to your question. Probably video driver did not build.